# Display Toast from AsyncTask until event occurs

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

I would like to display "Connecting ..." using Toast **until** the device is connected to a new network (more specifically when an IP address is obtained, see the while loop in doInBackground below). I am using AsyncTask for connecting to the network, but if I put Toast.makeText(...).show() inside onProgressUpdate() the toast calls will stack and end up displaying the text way longer than desired. My Connect class:

```
public class Connect extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Void>{
    private static final String TAG="sure2015test";
    private Context context;
    private Network network;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {

        this.network=(Network)params[0];
        this.context=(Context) params[1];
        final WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + network.ssid + "\"";
        if(network.password!=null){
            conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ network.password +"\"";
        }
        else{
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        }

        if(network.manager.addNetwork(conf)==-1){
            Log.i(TAG, "Add network fail");
        }
        List<WifiConfiguration> configs = network.manager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration i : configs) {
            if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + network.ssid + "\"")) {
                network.manager.disconnect();
                if(network.manager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true)==false){
                    Log.i(TAG,"Enable Network fail ");
                }
                if(network.manager.reconnect()==false) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Reconnect fail");
                }
            }
        }
        WifiInfo info=network.manager.getConnectionInfo();
        while((info.getIpAddress())==0){
            //Wait until non-zero IP address (once a non-zero ip address is obtained, you are connected to the network)
            //Tried to use NetworkInfo.DetailedState to check if it was CONNECTED
            //However the api method said it remained in OBTAINING_IPADDR state even after it obtained an ip (must be bug)
            info=network.manager.getConnectionInfo();
            publishProgress();
            Log.i(TAG,"IP "+info.getIpAddress());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                Log.i(TAG,"Interrupted exception");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Connecting ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(context, Device.class);
        newActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        newActivity.putExtra("Device", network.ssid);
        context.startActivity(newActivity);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't doable with Toast. Instead a more common practice is to show a Spinner for example which you can show and hide where desire.

Comment: @harism it should be. Make a final private Toast and use that text. In onProgressUpdate you want to call .show() then in onPostExecute call .cancel(). I'm on my phone now so I haven't tried but give that a shot. Although, yes, a spinner may be  better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) instead of a `Toast`. You can show it before running the `AsyncTask` and hide it `onPostExecute`. It'd look something like.-

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CurrentActivity.this, "", "Connecting...", true, false);

[...]

dialog.dismiss();
```

By the way, don't forget to put your string literals in a `Strings` resources file :)

Answer (score 0):

Toast is not a good practise to show progress work. Toast is designed to show minor and fast information(ex.  In your case is to show that devise is connected), but in my opinion it's better to implement `ProgressBar` in your layout and set it visible while `AsyncTask` execute `doInBackground` and set it invisible in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show Toast within the other thread, also within doInBackground(Object... params), you can use:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //put here your thread
    }
});
```

Hovewer, you need to get Context in this case. I make it with static variable. But do not forget, the Toast is appearing only for short time and you can't manage it. If you need to show the message all the time you do some stuff, you can use [ProgressDialog](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/progressdialog/android-progressdialog-example/)